# Get operation details of a Call Operation Action in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a CallOperation Action in my Activity diagram. How to get the operation set to the call operation action via DB or through API.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you link your Calloperation to an actual operation in the model it looks like this:

[image]

You can select the operation using the Behavior tab in the properties

[image]

The API does not expose this information, so you have to find it yourself.

The GUID of the operation is stored in the database field `t_object.Classifier_guid`. You can use the method `EA.Repository.GetMethodByGuid()` to get to the operation.

Here how it's implemented in my [framework](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAWrappers/CallOperationAction.cs)

```
        /// <summary>
        /// The operation to be invoked by the action execution.
        /// </summary>
        public UML.Classes.Kernel.Operation operation { 
            get{
                // first get the operations guid which is stored in the Classifier_guid column
                XmlDocument operationGUIDxml = this.EAModel.SQLQuery(@"select o.Classifier_guid from t_object o
                                    where o.Object_ID = " + this.id.ToString());
                XmlNode operationGUIDNode = operationGUIDxml.SelectSingleNode(this.EAModel.formatXPath("//Classifier_guid"));
                return this.EAModel.getOperationByGUID(operationGUIDNode.InnerText);
            }
            set{
                // no API method available, so we need to update the database directly
//              this.model.executeSQL(@"update t_object
//                                      set Classifier_guid = "+ ((Operation)value).GUID
//                                    + "where Object_ID = " + this.id.ToString();
                //TODO add GUID property to Operation
                throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
        }
```

Comment: The Classifier_guid is null for that CallOperation action :(

Comment: I added an explanation on how to set the reference to an operation correctly.